# does ObjectMapper retain any state info on the conversion it processes?

Tags: java, jackson

I'm looking for verification/correction on the following -- just not to miss out

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` doesn't retain any state after a mapping operation, especially upon calling its `.writeValueAsString(Object)`?

I'll have one `ObjectMapper` used several places and on different types of objects in the code. I'm wondering if there would be any trouble at all out of this.

Comment: Pretty sure it caches information about the classes. e.g. what public methods it has, what fields it has. Because it has to use reflection to get that info, and reflection is "slow" (relatively speaking), the cache is used to speed that up. Not sure when, if ever, that cache is invalidated. It shouldn't be stateful in a way that's observable, unless you're doing something really weird like redefining classes at runtime.

Comment: So in practice, no, it doesn't have any relevant state. You can safely reuse `ObjectMapper` instances, even from different threads at the same time.

Comment: To quote from the [javadoc](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.12.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html): _"Mapper instances are fully thread-safe provided that ALL configuration of the instance occurs before ANY read or write calls."_

Comment: @Michael write this an an ans and i'll accept

Comment: @Jorn write this as an ans and i'll upvote. can only accept 1 ans

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`ObjectMapper` is Thread-safe so you can use the same instance in different places and in different threads and it will work fine. In fact, using the same instance is a good practice.

Based on this fact I actually wrote a Json utility that provides static methods for serializing and de-serializing any arbitrary class instances to/from JSON. This utility is a thin wrapper over `ObjectMapper` class. Behind the scenes, I have a single instance of `ObjectMapper` class that is used for all the operations. This utility works well in multithreaded environments, which is the proof of my answer that you can safely use a single `ObjectMapper` instance in different places and different threads.

If you are interested you can check at my utility. Here is a [JsonUtils Javadoc](https://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). It comes as part of the Open Source MgntUtils java library written and maintained by me. you can get it as [maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc)